# Storing historical changes to data in SQL for reporting

Tags: sql, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I manage a booking application, I have been passed a PR to enable reporting, one of the reports I am being asked for is a report that shows untilisation of resources for a given date range.

I am trying to work out the best way of storing historical changes to resources so that I can accurately report utilisation percentages.

For example.

1st Jan through to 12th Jan, there may be 10 resources and if all 10 were booked every day then I would show 100% untilisation, however, if someone adds another 10 resorces at any point in the future my figures would be incorrect if the report was run again for the aformentioned date range after those resources were added.

I am thinking that I could potentially store a count in a different table that is just appended to if there is an add/delete of resources, is this the best soltion though? It feels very messy from a reporting perspective when I come to query the data later on as I could potentially have multiple rows of adds on a day for example that I would need to process.

I wanted to reach out to the minds here to see if there is a different angle of thinging that I could explore that mind lead me to a better solution.

My app is a dotnet 5 webapp, running in Azure, the app talks to Azure functions API which in turn uses Azure SQL for persistance.

Thank you so much in advance for any advice you can send my way!

Comment: Probably the best solution will be to use the provided support for [system versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/temporal-tables)

Comment: Do "resources" keep track (have a column) of when they have been "added" and "removed" ? Do you have a separate Table `| ResourcePKey | Added | Removed |` ? In your example ( computation for 1.-12. Jan) have you considered how to calculate in a resource being added on the 6th?

Comment: @Fildor thank you for your response, at the moment resources do not have an added/removed data, however, this is something that I could add, and a really useful suggestion thank you, I had not considered fully the adding of a resorce midway through the date range and a date added/removed column would make this reconcilliation easier. There are no extra tables yet, I am in a scope/discovery phase at the moment, my description above is a proposal at this point. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Stu I am going to check this out now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporal tables allows you to track and analyze the full history of changes in your data, without the need for custom coding. Saving any historical data will use extra database storage and other CPU resources because every CRUD operations will be saved as a separate entity in temporal table.

Depending on whether you are starting new development or upgrading existing application, you will either create temporal tables or modify existing ones by adding temporal attributes. Perform these actions on either SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) or as Transact-SQL statement.

1. In SSMS, use **Tables -> New -> System-Versioned Table...** path to create the temporal tables for existing tables.

[image]

2. Create temporal table using T-SQL.

**Note:** The mandatory elements of every temporal table are the PERIOD definition and the SYSTEM_VERSIONING clause with a reference to another user table that will store historical row versions:

```
CREATE TABLE WebsiteUserInfo
(  
    [UserID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , [UserName] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
  , [PagesVisited] int NOT NULL
  , [ValidFrom] datetime2 (0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START
  , [ValidTo] datetime2 (0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo)
 )  
 WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.WebsiteUserInfoHistory));
```

You can also extend the existing table to become temporal, as shown in the following example:

```
ALTER TABLE WebsiteUserInfo
ADD
    ValidFrom datetime2 (0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN  
        constraint DF_ValidFrom DEFAULT DATEADD(SECOND, -1, SYSUTCDATETIME())
    , ValidTo datetime2 (0)  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN
        constraint DF_ValidTo DEFAULT '9999.12.31 23:59:59.99'
    , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (ValidFrom, ValidTo);

ALTER TABLE WebsiteUserInfo  
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.WebsiteUserInfoHistory));
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IX_WebsiteUserInfoHistory
ON dbo.WebsiteUserInfoHistory
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/temporal-tables